# Any way to convert Business Account into person account using apex

Tags: visualforce, apex

I have a req in which i need to convert business account into person account. If anyone have idea to achieve this then please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what you've done and where you're stuck? I suspect the fact you've not done that is why you received the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the account has exactly one contact. Then, query for a record type where "IsPersonType" is true. Finally, set the record type for the account to the record type and save the change to the database.

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
insert a;
Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Test', AccountId=a.Id);
insert c;
RecordType t = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType = TRUE LIMIT 1];
a.RecordTypeId = t.Id;
update a; // This is now a person account when this call completes.
```